# use all global variables at once in php function

Tags: php, function, variables, global

I have a php script with approxx 50 global variables.
I have around 18 functions where I need the Global variables.

I need almost 40 global variables in most functions.
I included them now as:

```
      function example1() {
      global $1, $2, $3, ..... $40;
      }

      function example2() {
      global $1, $2, $3, ..... $40;
      }
```

Is there a more easier way to do this?

For example include all global variables at once?

In an array maybe?

I hope to hear some good suggestions!

Comment: Save these global variables in SESSION.

Comment: Just no, NO! Don't do this

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: First of all - just do not do this. I do not know what you want to do, but this is the worst solution. If you still want, then put all this variables in array and use just one global array instead.

Comment: I don't understand the question, what you want here? Even if you use array, still you need to call it individually, this is better solution only if you can use arrays in loop. Else you have to call it individually same as normal variable.

Comment: I have an array with a lot of data. Im checking each row on starttime and endtime. Between starttime and endtime are working hours. Lets say Starttime is 8:00 and endtime is 20:00. After 16:00 personel gets overtime hours. So I check if this is the case and the split the 'shift' in two shifts in a new array. Like from 8:00 to 16:00 and from 16:00 to 20:00. On the new array I check if the total working hours is longer then 8 hours. And so on and on. I know that the scripts itself works because I checked around 80 datasets.. If I dont use the global declaration I get no data in my new array...

Comment: Another option is declare it in config file, so here you have to include everytime

Comment: The reason why I would like to do so is because the functions go over the same array over and over again. If I make a new variable i have to change every function.

Comment: At the risk of **drawing fire**, as you appear to have coded yourself into a dark corner, there is always the globally available $GLOBALS array _An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope_ [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean. Maybe I have to clarify that the script only runs after a specific form is send. The dataset is only what has been filled in in the form. So I think because of that it is almost impossible that it would end up in a 'dark corner'. Thanks for the advice though, I will look into that.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't rewrite this code to not use global vars? It would not be hard to refactor this into a class and the function code would not have to change much.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has an extract function which converts all elements in an array to variables using their keys, that being said, since the $GLOBALS var contains all global variables, simple extract it in your function.

```
$name = 'John Doe';
function myFunction(){
  extract($GLOBALS);
  echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was handing a lot of variables over to global. I learned now that I had to at the & to the for each loop to directly modify the data in the array instead of declaring them and trying to hand them over to the global variables..

In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

```
      <?php
      $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
      foreach ($arr as &$value) {
          $value = $value * 2;
      }
      // $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
      unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
      ?>
```

Thanks for the help! I could delete a lot of codes and variables...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply include all the globals.

```
function myFunc() {
  foreach ($GLOBALS as $n => $v) {
     global $$n;
  }
  ... code using any global variable
}
```

Or you could include your own predefined subset.

```
$myGlobals = array('n1','n2');

function myFunc() {
  foreach ($GLOBALS['myGlobals'] as $n) {
     global $$n;
  }
  ... code using any global variable named in $myGlobals
}
```